# Hibernate Native SQLQuery extract values

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I extract multiple values from native SQLQuery?

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT param1, param2 from table_name where ..);
```

When I use `query.list()` or `query.uniqueResult`, it returns always list of Object\Object, which cannot be cast to anything even if I add scalars.
No problems on extraction single value:

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT param1 from table_name where ..);
Long result = (Long)query.uniqueResult();
```

But how can I extract 2 or more values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [SQLQuery.list() API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29):

> Return the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[]

Sample code:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT param1, param2 from table_name where ..);
List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>)query.list();//Object[] objs = (Object[])query.uniqueResult()
for (Iterator<Object[]> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Object[] e = iterator.next();
    String param1 = (String)e[0];//case object type to another by youself...
}
```

If your program add scalar to `SQLQuery`, *Hibernate* could return match object type as you expected.

Comment: Works only with scalars, this example also throws ClassCastException.
Btw, unqueResult can return Object[], not list

Comment: @ne1s, you are right. the sample code is for `query.list()`. I just edit it.